# Register user using ejs and carry session in node

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

I am learning node js and am trying to save the user details, using EJS and Node.

Below is my EJS file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<% include partial/nav.ejs %>

    <body>
        <% include partial/header.ejs %>
            <div id="body-content">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <div id="intro">
                    <p>This is an opportunity to meet and connect with old friend .<br>
                    Friends who are a part and parcel of life. <br> <br>
                    People who live far and apart use this as a platform to meet an greet each other. This platform is too connect some old connects. 

                    </p>
                </div>
                    <div id="body-left">
                    <form>
                        <p>
                            <label for="username"> Username </label>
                            <input type="text" for="username" name="username"/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password"> Password </label>
                            <input type="password" for="password" name="password"/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email"> Email </label>
                            <input type="text" for="email" name="email" />
                        </p>
                        <p> 
                            <label for="fNmame"> First Name </label>
                            <input type="text" for="fNmame" name="fNmame" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="lName"> Last Name </label>
                            <input type="text" for="lName" name="lName" />
                        </p>

                        <button type="submit">Log In</button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                <form action="/uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p>
                        <label for="profilePic"> Profile Image </label>
                        <input type="file" for="profilePic" name="profilePic" />
                    </p>
                    <button type="submit">Log In</button> 
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//create a schema
var loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    email:String,
    fNmame:String,
    lName:String
});

//user model
var Users = mongoose.model('users',loginSchema);

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

module.exports=function(app){

    app.get('/index',function(req,res){ 
        res.render('index2');
    });

    app.get('/register',function(req,res){
            res.render('register');
    });

    app.post('/register',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
        session=req.session;
        Users(req.body).save(function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(" back from ajax with data :::; " + data);
            req.session.user='sasdad';      
            res.status(200).send('User saved successfully');
        });
    });

};
```

and my client side script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form').on('submit', function(){

      var items = $('form');
      var user = {
            username: $('[name=username]', items).val(),
            password: $('[name=password]', items).val(),
            email: $('[name=email]', items).val(),
            fNmame: $('[name=fNmame]', items).val(),
            lName: $('[name=lName]', items).val()
          };

      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: '/register',
          data: user,
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            var resp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log(resp);
            var userD = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
            if(resp["status"]==200){
                console.log("status == 200");
                var userId = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                var regStatus= "registered";
                window.location.href = '/index';

            }  
              return data;
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log("inside error");
          }
        });

     return false;
  });  

});
```

I want to register the userid in the session ( once saved and carry it to the index page to display a success message.

Please also help me with the syntax to be used in the index page.

Comment: I don't think session support is built into express, but there are libraries that add it as middleware such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session which I think will add what is missing from your code.

Comment: I read about it, but am not able to implement it. First reason being I am using window.redirect where as I should be using res.render. But res.render is not redirecting the user thus only option I have is window.redirect

Comment: res.render runs on node (server side) and determines the html output of the http request, while window.redirect runs on the browser (client side) and tells the browser to send off a new http request.  If you want to preserve some session between the two request then you need to establish a cookie (or add your session into your URL as I think some web frameworks do).  You can set the cookies inside node with this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies and avoid the need to use any middleware (this is what I do in my node projects)

Comment: @jason-sperske, can you please help me with an example. I do not know how to use cookie in EJS or how to use cookie at client side